# Ansatz for the differential equation $y''-6x+9=10xe^{3x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, soft-question

I want to find an ansatz to find the particular solution for the differential equation $y''-6x+9=10xe^{3x}$.

I came up with $y_p(x)=(A_0+A_1x)e^{3x} + A_2 + A_3x+A_4x^2+A_5x^3$ in this case.

Are there other possible ansätze one can use here? Can my ansatz be simplified?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't write this as $y''=10xe^{3x}+6x-9$? At worst the the first term will require integration by parts (twice)?

Comment: @Semiclassical It is $y′′−6x+9$ on the left.

Comment: @JonathanZ I just wrote it like this because the exercise was formulated in the same way.

Comment: Okay. Well, you could transform it to my version, but maybe you're supposed to get practice with DEs formatted like that. But seeing it written that way I've got a really strong feeling that it was meant to be $y''-6y+9$ instead. I'd suggest double checking with someone, if you can, before continuing to spend time on this version.

Comment: @JonathanZ This problem was on a recent exam so the formulation should be correct.